# javascript regex - splitting a text into sentences on . if no number is before it

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a text into sentences, by using:

```
srt.replace(/(\.+|:|!|\?)(\s|\n|\r|\r\n)/gm, "$1$2|").split("|");
```

Which works great, but... If a sentence starts with a list number (i.e `"1. some words"`) I get: `['1.', 'some words']`.

It's my first time using regex and while I know there's a way to lookbehind I was not able to use it.
How can I change my regex to only split at . if there's no number character before it?

Comment: I don't see how you're going to be able to tell between a numbered list, and a sentence that ends with a number.

Comment: Don't split on pattern `^\d+\.`, which means you have number at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I won't, but it's an edge case I am willing to tolerate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using `str.replace(/(?<!:)(\n)\s*/g, "$1|").replace(/(?<![0-9])(\.+)\s*/g, "$1|").replace(/(\?+|!+)\s*/g, "$1|").split("|")`

I am sure there's a prettier way to write this regex, but as a noob - I don't yet know how. This also covers:
1. Not splitting if there's a new line after :
2. Multiple dots, question and exclamation marks

This code is meant to split a text into "ideas", which is why I used the conditions I did, might not be the right logic for a simple "split to sentences" need.